# Можно ли написать программу для android, которая, не запускаясь в среде ART или dalvik, будет работать в графическом режиме?

Tags: android

Как я знаю, все приложения андроид запускаются на виртуальной машине, подобной jvm, но более оптимизированной. Можно ли как-нибуть, пользуясь кросс-компайлингом, собрать программу, которая будет работать в графическом режиме? Именно программу для ядра linux? Я знаю, что меня назовут самоубийцей, но кого не затруднит, ответьте!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению андройд не даёт никаких возможностей запуска пользовательских приложений совсем без использования jvm. Но из Java кода можно передать управление нативному, который может например напрямую работать с графикой, так например делают большинство графических движков. Но данные с сенсеров всёравно придется получать через прослойку Java кода...

PS а с чего вы взяли что ART или dalvik более оптимизированные? Это вопрос довольно спорный и по большей части скорее всего не в пользу гугловских JVM

Comment: Ну по идее, гугловские рантаймы создавались как среды выполнения, которые будут восполнять недостаток железа устройства своей высокой производительностью и относительно малым размером. Сейчас это конечно же не актуально, потому что выходят в продажу устройства сильнее моего ПК.